# Perceptron linearly separable but not linearly separable through the origin

Tags: machine-learning

Can anyone explain the solution to this problem?

"Provide two points, (x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>) and (y<sub>0</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>) in two dimensions that are linearly separable but not linearly separable through the origin. Enter a Python list with two entries of the form [[x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>], label] where label is 1 or -1. (So each entry represents a point with 2 dimensions and its label)"

One of the solutions is "There are many possible answers for this question. In the provided solution, [[[1, 1], 1], [[2, 2], -1]], the points are linearly separable, but not through the origin".

But I want to know other answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find two points ($x_0$,$x_1$) and ($y_0$,$y_1$) linearly separable but not through the origin, you need to select two distinct points, among the infinite set of points, such that there is no potential classifier (hyperplane) passing through the origin and at the same time correctly classify both the two points.

Other possible solutions can be:

$[[[1, 1], 1], [[ 3, 3], -1]]$

$[[[2, 2], 1], [[ 3, 3], -1]]$

$[[[2, 2], 1], [[ -3, -3], 1]]$